# How to test an "electrified" appliance

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have an old appliance (Hobart mixer) that recently started to give me electrical shocks when I touch it.

I didn't see any obvious signs of broken wiring, but I will probably replace it, as it's fairly old.

Now - once I've done that, how can I test that the frame *isn't* electrified anymore? (I'd rather *not* use my hand for it...) I have a multimeter and a contactless voltage tester.

Comment: This sounds like a classic case for GFCI. Do you use it connected to a GFCI-protected receptacle? If not (e.g., older kitchen without GFCI), can you plug it in to a GFCI receptacle (e.g., bathroom) and see if it trips the GFCI?

Comment: That location doesn't have any GFCI outlets I could use.

I tested the outlet, and it seems like hot and neutral are reversed there, but I assume that has always been like that, so it's probably not the cause. (Since the shocks only started to happen recently, I suspect wiring gone bad inside the machine.)

Comment: Unplug the appliance, check resistance on the appliance power cord from live to ground, then from neutral to ground. I think those should be infinite, but will not be if there's a ground fault.

Comment: Is the chassis grounded? Basically I'm asking if the power plug has 3 prongs or 2 prongs.

Comment: If it's 2-prong, test using a metal part on the chassis instead of the earth pin. (Actually, test using that as well, just in case the earth pin doesn't go anywhere.)

Comment: Don't ever plug it in again, except to a GFCI protected outlet.  It doesn't need to be a GFCI receptacle with the test/reset buttons, any outlet will do as long as a GFCI tester trips it.

Comment: "Is the chassis grounded? Basically I'm asking if the power plug has 3 prongs or 2 prongs."

It has 3 prongs, and the three wires all seem to be connected properly.

Comment: Is the mixer on a 2 prong plug. I remember when I was a kid getting a shock from my grandma’s toaster, she unplugged it ant turned the plug over and plugged it back in, no more shock, back then the frames were on the neutral so if it was plugged in wrong the shock, if it’s a 3 wire plug time for a new mixer or to have this one repaired, I would agree in any case it should be on a GFCI circuit.